# How to send right query in AutocompleteInput in react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

I use

```
<ReferenceInput reference={'data-systems'} source={'masterSystemId'}>
     <AutocompleteInput optionText={"key"} optionValue={"id"}/>
</ReferenceInput>
```

And I expect that react-admin send query like `localhost/data-systems?filter={key: <VALUE_FROM_INPUT>}`
BUT! really query is `filter={q: <VALUE_FROM_INPUT>}` that doesn't work :(
Is there a way to send right fieldname?

Answer (score 0):

its need to add `filterToQuery={searchText => ({ key: [searchText]})` to `ReferenceInput`